# Can i use HTML tables in mobile webapps?

Tags: web-applications

I am developing a web app for **Android, iOS, Blackberry** mobiles, using **Jquery Mobile** and **Phonegap**. My question is can i use **HTML tables** in that? I know jQuery mobile has grid feature for that, but for some reason its convenient for me to use tables instead of grid. So does it gonna hamper the webapp in any way? is it supported on mentioned Mobile platforms? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use HTML tables only if your data is semantically a table, but never for layout.

Comment: Thanks. I am gonna use it for Displaying tabular data only.